# Netbeans Glassfish giving 404 on webservice, but not a JSP page

Tags: netbeans

I created a "WebApplication" in NetBeans.  It has a JSP page and a webservice.  It was working fine.  Then I made a few minor changes and redeployed.  Suddenly the webservice gives a 404 (Not Found) error.  GlassFish is still up and I can even hit a JSP page in the same project and changes to the JSP page are recognized.

Here's my deploy output:

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Building jar: C:\Documents and Settings\randys\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication6\dist\WebApplication6.war
Starting GlassFish V3
GlassFish V3 is running.
Incrementally deploying WebApplication6
Completed incremental distribution of WebApplication6
Incrementally redeploying WebApplication6
redeploy?name=WebApplication6&properties=keepSessions=true running on GlassFish V3
redeploy?name=WebApplication6&properties=keepSessions=true completed on GlassFish V3
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/WebApplication6/
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 41 seconds)
```

and

```
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Apache Felix OSGi platform
Welcome to Felix.
=================
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-mbeanserver [7]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.core.kernel [103]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.common-util [84]
INFO: Started bundle GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [68]
INFO: APIClassLoader = Class Loader for Bundle [GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [68] ]
INFO: registering service = org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl@676437, contract = org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel, name = null
INFO: registering service = org.apache.felix.framework.PackageAdminImpl@1e808ca, contract = org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin, name = null
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.branding.branding [31]
no resource bundle found for version, using default GlassFish version
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.internal-api [88]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.admin.config-api [76]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.registration.glassfish-registration [98]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-autodeploy [61]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-common [94]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.flashlight.flashlight-framework [97]
INFO: Listening on port 8080
INFO: Network listener http-listener-2 on port 8181 disabled per domain.xml
INFO: Listening on port 4848
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.container-common [106]
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.persistence.jpa-connector [65]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.webservices.jsr109-impl [70]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.scripting.gf-jruby-connector [60]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.gf-web-connector [121]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.security [63]
INFO: security.secmgroff
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.securitycommon [19]
INFO: Security startup service called
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-naming [90]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.realms [74]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-api [107]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-runtime [23]
INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
INFO: registering service = org.glassfish.web.DirContextURLStreamHandlerService@12d26d2, contract = org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService, name = null
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.web-glue [113]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.transaction.jta [57]
INFO: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://RANDYS-LAPTOP:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.dol [8]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.web-core [130]
INFO: Dual registration of jndi stream handler: factory already defined
INFO: Unknown loader 113.0 class org.apache.felix.framework.searchpolicy.ContentClassLoader
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.jstl-connector [119]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.jsf-connector [126]
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate as the delegate
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.work-management [37]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-ee-api [50]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-internal-api [111]
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Unknown loader 113.0 class org.apache.felix.framework.searchpolicy.ContentClassLoader
INFO: policy.loading
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.war-util [122]
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.websecurity [115]
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78 class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78 class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Loading WebApplication6 Application done is 10032 ms
INFO: GlassFish v3 Prelude startup time : Felix(7062ms) startup services(13173ms) total(20235ms)
INFO: classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78
INFO: SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@1ba5016
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78 class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78 class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Deployment of WebApplication6 done is 3156 ms
INFO: Server shutdown initiated
INFO: classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1e14a78
INFO: SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@1ba5016
SEVERE: PWC3983: Coyote connector has not been started
SEVERE: PWC3983: Coyote connector has not been started
INFO: PWC1240: Container WebModule[] has not been started
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] exiting
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.common-util [84]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.registration.glassfish-registration [98]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.security.websecurity [115]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.web-core [130]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.deployment.dol [8]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.security.securitycommon [19]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.persistence.jpa-connector [65]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.security.realms [74]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.webservices.jsr109-impl [70]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.war-util [122]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.container-common [106]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.jstl-connector [119]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.glassfish-api [107]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-internal-api [111]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.jsf-connector [126]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.admin.config-api [76]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.scripting.gf-jruby-connector [60]
INFO: Stopped bundle = GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [68]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-runtime [23]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.glassfish-ee-api [50]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.glassfish-naming [90]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.branding.branding [31]
INFO: removing service = org.glassfish.web.DirContextURLStreamHandlerService@12d26d2, contract = org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.web-glue [113]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-common [94]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.glassfish-mbeanserver [7]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.web.gf-web-connector [121]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.common.internal-api [88]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-autodeploy [61]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.connectors.work-management [37]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.flashlight.flashlight-framework [97]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.security.security [63]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.transaction.jta [57]
INFO: Stopped bundle = org.glassfish.core.kernel [103]
INFO: Stopped bundle = com.sun.enterprise.osgi-adapter [6]
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Apache Felix OSGi platform
Welcome to Felix.
=================
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-mbeanserver [7]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.core.kernel [103]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.common-util [84]
INFO: Started bundle GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [68]
INFO: APIClassLoader = Class Loader for Bundle [GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [68] ]
INFO: registering service = org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl@1982fc1, contract = org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel, name = null
INFO: registering service = org.apache.felix.framework.PackageAdminImpl@1e4853f, contract = org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin, name = null
no resource bundle found for version, using default GlassFish version
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.branding.branding [31]
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.internal-api [88]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.admin.config-api [76]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.registration.glassfish-registration [98]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-autodeploy [61]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-common [94]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.flashlight.flashlight-framework [97]
INFO: Listening on port 8080
INFO: Network listener http-listener-2 on port 8181 disabled per domain.xml
INFO: Listening on port 4848
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.container-common [106]
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.persistence.jpa-connector [65]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.webservices.jsr109-impl [70]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.scripting.gf-jruby-connector [60]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.gf-web-connector [121]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.security [63]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-naming [90]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-api [107]
INFO: security.secmgroff
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-runtime [23]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.securitycommon [19]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.transaction.jta [57]
INFO: Security startup service called
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.realms [74]
INFO: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://RANDYS-LAPTOP:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
INFO: registering service = org.glassfish.web.DirContextURLStreamHandlerService@162f030, contract = org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService, name = null
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.web-glue [113]
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.deployment.dol [8]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.web-core [130]
INFO: Dual registration of jndi stream handler: factory already defined
INFO: Unknown loader 113.0 class org.apache.felix.framework.searchpolicy.ContentClassLoader
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.jstl-connector [119]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.jsf-connector [126]
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate as the delegate
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.work-management [37]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-ee-api [50]
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-internal-api [111]
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Unknown loader 113.0 class org.apache.felix.framework.searchpolicy.ContentClassLoader
INFO: policy.loading
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.war-util [122]
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.websecurity [115]
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1bb35b class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1bb35b class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Loading WebApplication6 Application done is 10359 ms
INFO: GlassFish v3 Prelude startup time : Felix(4500ms) startup services(13328ms) total(17828ms)
INFO: classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1bb35b
INFO: SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@ef9d00
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1bb35b class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1bb35b class org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader
INFO: Loading application WebApplication6 at /WebApplication6
INFO: Deployment of WebApplication6 done is 3360 ms
```

I see several:

```
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
```

I don't use java messaging explicitly.  Any ideas why the WS is not deploying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ProcessExplorer, I found a bunch of java.exe's running with the following command-line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\bin\java" "-Djruby.home=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.5.1\ruby2\jruby-1.1.4" -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks" "-Djava.security.policy=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy" -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish/lib/endorsed" "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre/jre/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\javadb/lib" -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput "-XX:LogFile=C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1/logs/jvm.log" -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=2 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=3251,server=y,suspend=n -client -jar "C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\modules\glassfish.jar" --domain domain1 --domaindir "C:\Program Files\glassfish-v3-prelude\glassfish\domains\domain1"
```

It appears that NetBeans doesn't close them when I restart.  Other than forcibly killing the .exe's does NetBeans have a feature to kill the old one when I do a build?